# How can I create a clean Laravel 7 install for dev that won't try to update modeules to v8?

Tags: laravel

Despite all the improvements that v8 has delivered I'm having some fun with livewire npm interacting with UI/bootstrap, such as:

````
```> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
        throw err;
        ^

       Error: Cannot find module './utils/constants'```

... and ...



 ``` 
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxxxx\OneDrive\qqqq\xx\Laravel\login\node_modules\webpack\clibin\cli.js:8:34)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',```
````

So, to my point, is there a way to install a clean Laravel 7 that remains blissfully ignorant of v8 and any related consequences (dependencies)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#installing-laravel)? ;)

> #### Via Composer Create-Project
>
> Alternatively, you may also install Laravel by issuing the Composer
> `create-project` command in your terminal:
>
> ```
> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 blog
> ```

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't ^7.0 translate as 7.0 and above? Whereas I want 7.0 period.

Comment: I guess you could try it without the `^` then

Comment: @esskayaitch why would you want exactly 7.0? ... the latest version of 7 is 7.28.4